# A of B or B A (used adjectivally)

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

I am having a hard time understanding the function and meaning of "***of***" in some examples. According to [Cambdridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/of), one of the meaning of "***of***" is "THAT IS/ARE". I am not quite sure what that means.

And I wonder if it is possible to reverse the word order in those situations? Do they mean the same thing when they are reversed?
​

> ***man of steel*** to ***steel man***
>
> ***the pain of separation*** to ***the separation pain***
>
> ***the skill of negotiating*** to ***the negotiating skill***
>
> ***a bill of £42.50*** to ***a £42.50 bill***
>
> ***the meaning of obligation*** to ***the obligation meaning***

Answer (score 3):

In some of these cases you may reverse the order, but this often changes the nuance.  For example "the man of steel" by default, is considered a *figurative* expression, but "the steel man" is, by default, *literal*.  In this case "of" means something closer to "like" than "is".  Superman is not *made* of steel, but he is impenetrable *like* steel.

Unfortunately this is not consistent from expression to expression.  For example

> He is a **cupcake** man

can imply that he is soft and sweet *like* a cupcake -- which is to say, not a very tough guy.   In a different context it implies his favorite food is cupcake.  If you use the definite article ("*the* cupcake man") it says that he is a baker of cupcakes, with the nuance that he is quite good at it.

On the other hand:

> He is a **man of cupcakes**

implies the he is very knowledgeable about cupcakes.  It doesn't suggest he is figuratively made of cupcakes.

The rest of your examples are similarly problematic, and have to be explained separately.   For example, "the pain of separation" is fine, but "the separation pain" is odd.  This is mostly because, by default, it's assumed "separation" is connected in a compound noun with "pain", rather than referring to the cause of the pain.

It's much the same for "the meaning of obligation", although this would often be set off with quotes:

> the meaning of **"obligation"**

"The *obligation* meaning" is not idiomatic, again because, by default, it's assumed that that "obligation" creates a compound noun with "meaning", which makes no sense.

In a different way:  "negotiating skill" is fine, but "*the* negotiating skill" sounds odd.  It's fine with a possessive pronoun ("your", "his", "her", etc.), even better as a plural, and even better with "negotiation":

> Your **skills** of **negotiation** / your **negotiation skills**

"Negotiating" sounds OK with *at*, rather than *of*

> Your skill **at** negotiating

The only one that is commonly reversible is "a bill of £42.50", which means exactly the same thing the other way round ("a £42.50 bill").  It's likely that the more common preposition with bills is "for", though, assuming you are talking about a request *for* money, and not currency.

> a bill **for** £42.50

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer :).Could you explain that meaning of "of" I quoted in my question?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden   Dictionaries are good for many things, but for definitions of very common words, like prepositions, they're at best loose approximations and aren't very useful.  In many ways prepositions are *axiomatic*, in that they can't be defined by other words.  They mean whatever they mean in the context they are used.  Cambridge says "the pain **of** separation" uses "of" in the sense of "being", but it would be equally valid to say "of" indicates "possession" -- the *pain* that possesses the quality of "separation".

Answer (score 1):

Let's take these one at a time

> ```
> man of steel to steel man
> ```

These ought to mean the same thing but "man of steel" has connotations to Superman that steel man does not have.

> the pain of separation to the separation pain

These are very close; to me, the former sounds more natural. Google Ngram Viewer confirms that the former is much more common than the latter.

> ```
> the skill of negotiating to the negotiating skill
> ```

These are almost identical.

> ```
> a bill of £42.50 to a £42.50 bill
> ```

The latter sounds a *little* awkward because, in this context, it might be a piece of paper that was worth that amount. This would be worse if the amount was a round number.

```
the meaning of obligation to the obligation meaning
```